# Difficulty creating an Android app with Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am learning some java for writing simple android apps. Currently I'm working on a temperature converter, and running into problems if I do not enter a value for my input.

```
else if(tempfrom.equals("Rankine")){


        if(tempto.equals("Fahrenheit")){
            degreesout = degreesin - 459.67;
        }
        else if(tempto.equals("Celsius")){
            degreesout = (degreesin - 491.67)*(5./9.);
        }
        else if(tempto.equals("Kelvin")){
            degreesout = degreesin*(5./9.);
        }
        else{
            degreesout = degreesin;
        }
    }

    else if(degreesin.equals(null)){
        tempto = "Please Enter a Value.";
    }


    TextView answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdegreesout);
    TextView units = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUnit);
    units.setText(tempto);
    answer.setText(degreesout.toString() + " degrees");
```

Where `tempfrom` and `tempto` are Strings that correspond to temperature units for conversion. Basically, I'm checking that if `degreesin.equals(null)`, where degreesin is the input value, then set the string `tempto` to "Please Enter a Value." Then the text view at the bottom would change to say "Please Enter a Value."

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I just started java about two days ago, so it could be something silly :P

Comment: dont use the equals method to check for null. use "degreesin == null"

Comment: This is still not working. Here is how I have degreesin defined:
`Double degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString());`

Comment: can u show us the error you are getting?  post your logcat if possible

Comment: Here's the part that is showing errors. Is there anyway to expand on the "...14 more" part? I've tried exporting the log to a text file but it still shows up that way.

http://pastebin.com/YRwG8Czg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

`Double degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString());`

to

```
Double degreesin = 0;

if(!ettemp.getText().toString().equals("")){
    degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString());
}
```

The error your getting is caused by the parsing an empty `String` to `Double`. The above will check for an empty `String` and will only parse the value if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Double degreesin = null

if(ettemp != null && ettemp.getText() != null && !ettemp.getText().equals("")){
    degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettem.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are setting the degreesin value like that

```
String degreesin = txtDegreesIn.getText().toString();
```

you have to check for an empty value as follows:

```
if (degreesin.trim().length() == 0){
     // handle an empty input
}
```

this will also disallow inputs like " ".

answer to your comment:

```
Double degreesin = null;
try {
    degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    // empty/invalid input
}
```

Comment: This is how degreesin is setup:
`Double degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString())`
It's type double, so I changed your code to `if (degreesin.toString().trim().length() == 0){
     // handle an empty input
}`
and I'm still getting the same type: `03-28 08:52:28.201: E/AndroidRuntime(13806): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
`

Comment: assign degreesin as follows:
Double degreesin = null;
try {
    degreesin = Double.parseDouble(ettemp.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
    // empty input 
}